# System.FormatException: String '2021-03-13 11:22:54.3100000' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime-format

Below is the line that is throwing error:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
   x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.dte == "Date")?.Value, 
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

May I know where I am going wrong.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff`

Comment: Format is missing for miliseconds. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#fffffffSpecifier

Comment: Thank you, when I add milliseconds as suggested. now it says "System.FormatException: String '2023-03-23 11:03:10' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
"

Comment: I believe I have dates coming in two formats, one with milliseconds and one without milliseconds. Do we have option to add both formats?

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *optional* fraction of seconds, try *capital* `F` instead of `f`; so for the format string

`"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF"`

you'll get

```
string[] tests = {
  "2021-03-13 11:22:54.3100000",
  "2021-03-13 11:22:54"
};

var results = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests.Select(test =>
  $"{DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF", null):d MMMM yyyy : HH.mm.ss.ff}"));

Console.Write(results);
```

Output:

```
13 March 2021 : 11.22.54.31
13 March 2021 : 11.22.54.00
```

**Edit:** if you have *several* different formats, just pass them as an array:

```
string text = "2023-03-23 11:03:10";

var result = DateTime.ParseExact(text, 
  new string[] { //TODO: Put all the formats here
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF",
    "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF",
  }, 
  null, 
  DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

the system will try formats in the order you put them until it finds the fit one or throws exception if none of the formats fits the `text`.

Comment: But I could see, there is one more format. Sorry, I was not aware. Now the third format is not recognized 1)  '2023-03-13 11:22:54.3100000' 2) '2023-03-23 11:03:10'  3) '30.03.2023 14:32:28'

Comment: I would appreciate if you could give me an idea of how I can include this format "30.03.2023 14:32:28" to the already existing two. Thank you.

Comment: @st27 You're using `ParseExact` meaning that the datetime values need to exactly match the format you specify. If you need to specify more formats, use the `ParseExact` overload that takes a list of them.

Comment: @st27: I've edited the answer: if you have *many different formats* to try, just put them into an array.